# How to restore accidentally deleted "Servers" folder in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, webserver

I accidentally removed a "Servers" directory from "Project Explorer" / "Navigator" view in Eclipse. My server is still shown in the "Servers" tab. The `Servers/` directory is presented on the disk in the workspace directory.

How could I restore the "Servers" directory without configuring the servers manually again from scratch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the "Servers" directory is considered by Eclipse as a regular project. So, you can import that back as an existing project:

1. Choose <kbd>File</kbd> → <kbd>Import</kbd> → <kbd>General</kbd> → <kbd>Existing Projects into Workspace</kbd>
2. Click <kbd>Next</kbd>
3. Choose "Select root directory", click <kbd>Browse</kbd> and select your existing `Servers/` directory on a disk